# How to bind a string variable to datepicker control instead of a date object?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am using [Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) datepicker in my project.

The control has an option "datepicker-popup" which allows me to set up te format I want to display the date in. However the date is bound to my model as a date object and not as a formatted string.

The rest of my code simply requires  the date as a string in the correct (yyyy-MM-dd) format.

At the moment wehenever I need to use the date, I format it to the correct string before passing it along.

This works for now since The code base is pretty small but is there a better way to somehow bind the date to my model as a string so that someone forgetting to format the date before using it doesn't break the system.

A [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FLblIpegdcs09Gbmjono?p=preview) for the sample code can be found here.

I was thinking maybe I would need to set up a watch or something but was not too sure what the correct solution would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently AngularUI and many other frameworks use the Date object to bind information. You need to format the date to a string each time you want it as a string. The way to do this is to create a function like

```
$scope.getMyDateAsString = function(){
    return myDate.toString(); // or however you format your string.
};
```

Then anytime you want to get the string you can call this function. You CAN create a watcher

```
$scope.$watch($scope.myDateModel, function(newVal, oldVal){
    $scope.myDateAsString = $scope.getMyDateAsString();
});
```

This way, anytime the datepicker changes value, you change the value of the string.

Comment: I tried to get the watch to work but it only gets triggered on page load. http://plnkr.co/edit/FLblIpegdcs09Gbmjono?p=preview

Comment: Please ignore my earlier comment. I think i broke something on plunker but the watch seems to be working in my project. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 6):

I think that I found better solution for this. You can use your own parser for datepickerPopup directive. Example which works for me (you have to add this directive to the application):

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('datepickerPopup', function (){
        return {
            restrict: 'EAC',
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
                ngModel.$parsers.push(function toModel(date) {
                    return date.getFullYear() + '-' + (date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + date.getDate();
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Each when you will select the date on date picker you will have the String object with formatted date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can format your dates after picking, using [Cordova Plugin Datepicker](https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker) and [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), this solution works for me:

```
$scope.pickSinceDate = function(){
    pickDate($scope.filter.since).then(function(date){
        $scope.since = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.